# If $A,B$ are random variables of different distributions, and $\mathbb{E}(A)=\mathbb{E}(B)$, is it necessary for $P(A>B)=P(A<B)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

As the title asks, If $A,B$ are random variables of different distributions, and $\mathbb{E}(A)=\mathbb{E}(B)$, is it necessary for $P(A>B)=P(A<B)$? I tried letting $A\sim Uniform()$ and $B\sim Bin(n,p)$. Made sure the expectation is the same, then calculated $Pr(A>B), Pr(A<B)$ using python for some values of $n,p$ at it was true, but I am wondering if it holds in general.

Comment: what is $E(A)$?

Comment: @gt6989b Expectation

Comment: @gt6989b Edited

Comment: Hint: Try something where $A$ and $B$ are supported at two points.  For instance, $A$ is supported at $0$ and $1$.  And $B$ is supported at $0$ and $1000$.  Then, make both expectations equal to $.5$ and check your inequalities.

Comment: @MichaelBurr  I already tried to do that (not your supports, but similar) but I can't come up with a $\bf concrete$ example where both probabilities are not the same and verify this with python.

Comment: Python and programming shouldn't be even close to necessary or at the front of your mind.  This can be solved with pen and paper.  MichaelBurr's suggestion leads to a specific concrete example.  There is a unique random variable $A$ whose support is $\{0,1\}$ whose expectation is $0.5$.  It can be found using high school algebra solving the linear equation in one variable: $0.5 = 0\cdot p + 1\cdot (1-p)$.  Similarly you can explicitly find what $B$ is.  Now... you should be able to see what the joint distribution is.

Comment: The short answer is no, your claim is false.

Comment: Alright, I see it now. Let $A$ be an event of coin flip (0 or 1). Let $B$ be rv which is 0 with probability $1/2000$  then both have the same expectation, but $Pr(A>B) = 1/4000$ while $Pr(A<B)= 1999/2000) $ which is much bigger. I’m guessing my problem was that I was choosing non skewed distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on MichaelBurr's hint...

Let $A$ be a random variable with support $\{0,1\}$ with expectation $0.5$

It follows that $Pr(A = k) =\begin{cases} 0.5 & \text{if }k=0\\0.5&\text{if }k=1\end{cases}$

Let $B$ be a random variable with support $\{0,1000\}$ with expectation $0.5$ and be independent of $A$.

It follows that $Pr(B = k) = \begin{cases}\frac{1999}{2000}&\text{if }k=0 \\\frac{1}{2000}&\text{if }k=1000\end{cases}$

You get that $B>A$ if and only if $B = 1000$.  You get then that $Pr(B>A)=\frac{1}{2000}$

You get that $A>B$ if and only if $A=1$ and $B=0$.  You get then that $Pr(B<A)=Pr(B=0)Pr(A=1)=\frac{1999}{2000}\cdot 0.5 = \frac{1999}{4000}$ which is not equal to $\frac{1}{2000}$, thus disproving your claim.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out as you wrote it. Thanks regardless.